# htaccess to force extensionless works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
https://admin.mydomain.com/log/general
```

The file is actually general.php

I use the following .htaccess at my previous server

```
# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Its work at my previous server but not my new server, mod rewrite is enabled and I did add the directive in my conf file. not sure why it doesn't work when I key in

```
https://admin.mydomain.com/log/general
```

it doesn't load the general.php file and it give me a 404 not found.
Could it be my mod rewrite done wrongly?

This my root .htaccess content

```
Order deny,allow

RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php


Phpinfo()

Loaded Modules  core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status
```

Below is my apache2 sites config details:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName account.mydomain.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/biz/admin
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /var/www/priv888.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/priv888.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/priv888.crt
                SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/priv888.ca-bundle


                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
<Directory /var/www/biz/admin>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**THANKS FOR HELPING**